# How to set up format string

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I have the following code:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_z_function_surface(equation="%f*x**2+%f*y**2"(%a,%a))
```

but it throws error:

> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Can anyone help me how to modify this code?

Comment: Hello and welcome. You need to provide more details. What are you trying to do in `"%f*x**2+%f*y**2"(%a,%a)` ?

Comment: I hope to generate a random quadric surface, where %f and %f are two random coefficent

Answer (score 0):

This sample script generates 2 random integers within the range $0$ to $5$ and substitutes them in your equation to generate the z-surface

```
import bpy
import random

def get_random():
    return random.randint(0,5) # or use random.uniform(0,5) for floats

r1 = get_random()
r2 = get_random()

equation = f"{r1}*x**2+{r2}*y**2"
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_z_function_surface(equation=equation)
```